str_to_date is showing NULL when date is available
I was using an UPDATE query to fix my dates.  It's the same query with a CASE statement that I've used before.  It checks if the VARCHAR date is blank, if so, then set to NULL.  Otherwise, change the format of the date.
For some reason, it's setting all of the dates to NULL.
After re-importing the data, I started using a SELECT (which is probably the better practice).  Here is the SELECT:
SELECT `dateColumn`, CASE `dateColumn`
  WHEN '' THEN NULL
  ELSE date_format(str_to_date(`dateColumn`, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i:%s %P'), '%Y-%m-%d')
  END AS 'NEW DATE'
FROM `table` where `EmailAddress` = 'myemail@yahoo.com';

This gives me these results:
      dateColumn      | NEW DATE
----------------------------------------
9/9/2024 12:00:00 AM  | NULL

The format seems correct.  Not sure why it's changing the date to NULL.
Please help.
** EDIT **
I just noticed that I am getting a warning that reads:
Warning: #1411 Incorrect datetime value: '9/9/2024 12:00:00 AM' for function str_to_date

Unlikely that is causing the error.

the format you are using does not match the date %m-%d-%Y "-" is different from "/"

@JorgeCampos - I just fixed it.  It was a typo.  Using the above, I am getting the NULL when there is a date.

WHEN datecolumn = ’’

@MichaelLogothetis - Good catch, but no luck.  Date is still showing as NULL when it should be in the updated date format.  I don't get it.

There is no uppercase %P the documentation states lowercase %p for am/pm. str_to_date will return null if it can't parse the format.
Also since you have AM/PM hours you should use %h which is 01 to 12.
I also changed the case syntax a bit.
SELECT dateColumn,
CASE when dateColumn = '' THEN NULL
  ELSE date_format(str_to_date(dateColumn, '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s %p'), '%Y-%m-%d')
  END AS "NEW DATE"
FROM (select '09/09/2024 12:00:00 AM' as dateColumn) a;

See it working here: https://sqlfiddle.com/mysql/online-compiler?id=54541e8d-2bd1-43bc-93b9-e62a511aab0a

I stared at your solution for 5 minutes trying to figure out what was the difference between my query and yours.  Turns out that it was the dashes.  This doesn't make sense to me.  Previously, the query wouldn't run if the dateformatting wasn't correct.  Well, anyway, thank you for your help.  This solved my issue.

No problem. You mentioned on the comments the dashes were a typo, so I looked for something else and the main difference was the format you provided on yours: '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i:%s %P' mine: '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s %p' :)  "P" over "p" also the uppercase "H" but that wouldn't make a difference in that particular sample

Simple .. ELSE str_to_date(dateColumn, '%m/%d/%Y') .. is enough.
